# Manipulate the total row to only sum the first row of every unique order in a list

Tags: powerbi, dax

This might be a strange question and not sure if it is possible to accomplish this with a Power BI table. My goal is to make the total row display the sum of the first row (Operation flag = 1) of every order in a list.

Logically the summarizing total row would produce the below result by summarizing all the rows in the "Manufactured Qty" column. (The below is just a manually created example in Excel to illustrate)

[image]

The desired DAX logic should instead produce the below result i.e. summarizing the quantity of every "Order no" with "Operation flag" equal to 1 in the total row.

[image]

Best regards,
Rubrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to use a measure instead of the column. In this measure, use [HASONEVALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/hasonevalue-function-dax) to check if the value is for a data row or for the totals row and either return the sum of all rows (for the normal case) or the sum of the rows where `Operation flag` = 1 (for the totals).

```
Manifactured Qty Measure = 
    var allRows = SUM('Table'[Manifactured Qty])
    var firstOnly = CALCULATE(sum('Table'[Manifactured Qty]),'Table'[Operation flag] = 1)
    RETURN IF(HASONEVALUE('Table'[Manifactured Qty]), allRows, firstOnly)
```

[image]